# Am I able to get a UK passport

Tags: united-kingdom, passport

I wanted to ask if it was possible for me to get a British passport. I was born in the UK but both me and my parents are not British. So am I able to get a passport?

Comment: Start here: https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen

Comment: The question is whether you are British or not, so I don't understand the statement that you are not British.

Comment: What i mean is both my parents aren't British. So i am not considered as British citizen. What I wanted to know is since I was born in the UK will I be able to get a passport?

Comment: @Ahmad: The answer to your question may depend on many factors, not only where you were born. The UK government web site (linked in my comment above) has a good online questionnaire which should answer your question.

Comment: @Ahmad on the contrary, if at least one of your parents was "settled" in the UK at the time of your birth, you are a British citizen. If you were born before 1983, the "settled" requirement doesn't apply; in that case you're even more likely to be British.  In neither case is it a requirement for the parent to be British.

Comment: Please add more details on your situations. Important details are when you were born, and what the status of your parents was when you were born (like whether they had ILR at that time or not). The answer can be reopened after that

Comment: I will do the questionnaire thanks Greg HewGill and phoog my father had his PHD at that time and @SztupY I was born on 1/28/2000 and as i mentioned earlier my father had his PHD at that time

Comment: @Ahmad What do you mean by “had his PHD”? He was pursuing a PhD at a British university? What was his status? Where do you reside now?

Comment: @Gala He had his PHD years ago and yes at a British university by having his PHD I guess he was a student and now I am in my country Saudi Arabia